# Executing PHP Code in Javascript with Confirm()

Tags: php, javascript, confirm

I am trying to use javascript's confirm function to set my php variable $continue based on the confirm click.  I feel like the code below should work, but $continue is always false.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var answer;
    answer = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
    if (answer) { <?php $continue = true; ?> }
    else { <?php $continue = false; ?> };

    // -->
    </script>
```

Any help is always appreciated!

Comment: Pay attention that PHP works on server-side whereas JavaScript on the client-side. The only option is to send/receive data to/from PHP script.

Comment: Oh.. so the two $continue expressions are evaluated before the javascript executes?

Comment: Definitely. Even before the page is shown in your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

php is server side, javascript is client side.

if you need to change something via javascript do this using ajax. but you need keep this in your mind: the php just write html and process http requests. all of the interaction in the client side who will change some state in the server must perform a http request.